# C++ operator<< resolution

Tags: operator-keyword, resolution

For the following example code, the constant method C::m() is invoked:

```
class C
{
public:
    int m() const
    {
        std::cout << "const ";
        return x;
    }
    // int & m()
    // {
    //     std::cout << "nonconst ";
    //     return x;
    // }
private:
    int x;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "C().m(): " << C().m() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

If the non-constant C::m() is uncommented, then the non-constant C::m() is used instead of the constant C::m(). I've written several other scenarios and it seems that the non-constant method is preferred. Can someone point me to a relevant doc on the resolution for this case?

I can force the choice of the constant method:

```
std::cout << "C().m(): " << ((const C &)C()).m() << '\n';
```

But was wondering if there's a way to achieve the above without the cast.

The specific scenario I'm interested in is the following. I'm writing a class that uses a library which uses unsigned 8-bit int (i.e. unsigned char or uint8_t) for computation. For debugging printing, I prefer to see the unsigned char as an unsigned int. A minimal example is:

```
class C
{
public:
    uint8_t & x()
    { 
        return x_;
    }
    unsigned int x() const
    {
        return x_;
    }
private:
    uint8_t x_;
};
```

so that if c is a C object, I hope to do this:

```
c.x() = 0;                  // calls nonconstant C::x()
std::cout << c.x() << '\n'; // calls *constant* C::x(), print 0 and not '\0'
```

Is there a way to achieve the above, i.e., to force the operator<< to choose the constant C::x() without resorting

```
std::cout << ((const C &)c).x() << '\n';
```

or simply use the non-constant version but have to typecast the char to unsigned int:

```
std::cout << (unsigned int) c.x() << '\n';
```

Comment: If you have both a constant and no constant, then the constant will be essentially called on object declared const and the other one will be called otherwise. Thus the solution is to have only the const version or have another function `m_as_int` that returns the integer value. And by the way, you should never use C style cast in C++ code. Use `const_cast` instead.